# Ajax Link In A FAPI tableselect Row

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm trying to add an ajax link to my tableselect rows and replace part of this form with ajax.

```
$options = array();
foreach ($result as $camp) {
    $options[$camp->uuid] = array(
        'select_link' => array('data' => array(
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#name' => 'select_link',
            '#title' => t('use'),
            '#href' => 'ajax_use_data_callback/nojs/', 
            '#attributes' => array(
                'class'=>array(0=>'use-ajax')
            ),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'wrapper' => 'selected-data-div',
                'method' => 'replace',
            ),
        )),

        ...

    );
}
```

This triggers an alert with a 404 error and the site's default html. How do I tell this ajax link to be handled like a regular ajax form element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by building a `'select'` element with an option for each row id in the tableselect that gets an ajax link. Then we can add links to the tableselect row with `'#markup'` and use Drupal.behaviors to attach a function that sets the value of the select element and triggers its `'change'` event. In the form building function, if `$form_state['triggering_element']['#name']` is the new select element, `$form_state['triggering_element']['#value']` is the one we want to process.

The select element could then be hidden and the in-row ajax links are still fairly clean. Of course this won't work if javascript is off.

Answer (score -2):

you must declare hook_menu() for ajax_use_data_callback/nojs/ path

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @monymirza it might as well be an answer. Or at least part of an answer and the rest was so obvious to Rustam he didn't even mentioned it. I'm sure happened to the best of us sometimes.